# when interpolating a condition concatenating 'linear-gradient' as the value of 'background-image', the image disappears. why?

Tags: angular

I want that if my `effect` variable is `true`, the `linear-gradient` effect is shown, otherwise only the image is shown.

```
 picture =
'https://i.blogs.es/7c43cd/elon-musk-no-queria-ser-ceo-e-hizo-todo-lo-posible-para-evitarlo-pero-asegura-que-sin-el-tesla-moriria___/450_1000.jpg';
 effect = true;

<div 
 [style.background-image]="effect?'linear-gradient(to left, rgb(146 145 145) 20%, transparent 60%),':''+'url('+picture+')'">
</div>
```

**Desired output:**

when `effect=true`

```
background-image:linear-gradient(to left, rgb(146 145 145) 20%, transparent 60%),url('https://i.blogs.es/7c43cd/elon-musk...')
```

when `effect=false`

```
background-image: url('https://i.blogs.es/7c43cd/elon-musk...')
```

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-engypj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this expression:

```
<div class="container_image_ruling"
  [style.background-image]="effect ? 'linear-gradient(to left, rgb(255 255 145) 20%, transparent 60%),url(' + picture + ')' : 'url(' + picture + ')'">
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6dpzbr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)